# VectorAssembler creates string values instead of original integers

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I have the following PySpark DataFrame `df`:

```
df.printSchema()


 |-- yearday: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- month: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- dayofweek: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- year: integer (nullable = true)
```

When I apply `VectorAssembler`, the `features` are converted into `string` values instead of original `integer` values.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ['yearday', 'month', 'dayofweek', 'year'], outputCol = 'features')
df = vectorAssembler.transform(df)
df.select(['features']).show()
```

This is how the output looks like:

[image]

How can I get integers in `features`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's a display bug... it should be an integer. Try the code below to confirm what type the vectors contain.

```
from pyspark.ml.param import TypeConverters

print(TypeConverters.toList(df.select('features').take(1)[0][0]))
```

Comment: I get this output: `[286.0, 10.0, 3.0, 2015.0, 4.0, 42.0, 3.0, 0.0, 15.0]`. Then, I don't understand why this code fails `gbt = GBTRegressor(featuresCol = 'features', labelCol = 'data')   fitted = gbt.fit(df)` with the error `pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column data must be of type numeric but was actually of type string.`. I assumed that this error was caused by string values in `df`, but now I cannot understand the reasons.

Comment: it complains `data` column is of string type. What does the label/data column look like?

Comment: oh, right! indeed `printSchema` shows that `data` is a string. Thank you!